# Resolving to minmaj7

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions, cadence

Looking for possible resolutions to a imaj7.

Theoretical or not - shoot!

Out-of-the-ordinary resolutions are needed (I already know the theory behind it, using possible modes and all ).

Looking forward to discussing some resolutions.

one resolution to that I found was from ♭vii7.

Answer (score 7):

A minmaj7 chord can be the first degree (with the 7th) from the *harmonic minor scale*. So using progressions from that scale, you can have resolutions on minmaj7.

Here is a simple V-i:

[image]

Basically, since you are not looking only for theoretical answers, anything that sounds good to you works.

Also, if you are on any minor scale, on a V-i resolution, you can easily continue playing the leading tone (like I did on the example) and it would be a minmaj7 chord.

Comment: GNNNN! Even reading that snippet gives me an outright itch. That B _really_ wants to resolve up to C.

Comment: @leftaroundabout haha, I agree, I kept thinking this as a delayed resolution to C

Comment: XD  Yup that's true, but let's try to make it work :) Historically this non-functioning chord was used to resolve to the tonic so don't think of it in a classical way. Any weird and or abstract way to resolve into this is what this post is all about. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

resolving to i min maj7 isn't a classical style resolution since you're keeping the leading tone present, but strong examples are from V7 with extensions like b9,#9, or its tritone sub bII(dom)7

Comment: Agreed! it is a non-functioning chord, hence we won't find it being used much in classical. Although by digging around I did find the usage of minmaj7 in classical context too, however it was not used to resolve rather it  was used as a tension builder to resolve to the tonic. Also I have used the resolutions that you mentioned, using V7 to Iminmaj7th (kinda secondary dominant) and it sounds nice with #9 and sometimes with 13th but the tritone one is weird and I think it can be used for line cliches

Comment: Listen to the ending of *Invitation* by Bronisław Kaper for a nice example of an V7-altered to I minmaj7.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: "imaj7" in my answer means Am(maj7) in the key of A minor or the equivalent in other keys (the lowercase "i" covers the minor in mmaj7).*

Here are some voicings that sound cool (IMO, obviously).

**Ⅴ-♮ⅵ°-♮ⅶ°-ⅰmaj7** (G minor)

```
X:1
L:1/8
M:C
K:Gm
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] [^FAd]2 [GB=e][Ac^f] [GBdf]4
[V:B]  D,2     =E,^F,       G,4
```

**ⅱ°7-ⅰmaj7** (E minor)

```
X:1
L:1/2
M:C
K:Em
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] [FAc_e][B,^dg]
[V:B]  F,     E,
```

**♭Ⅱ7-ⅰmaj7** (F♯ minor)

```
X:1
L:1/2
M:C
K:F#m
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] ([=Fd]    [Fc])
[V:B]  [=G,,B,]  [F,,A,]
```

**♭Ⅴ9sus-ⅰmaj7** (personal favorite!) (A minor)

```
X:1
L:1/2
M:C
K:Am
%%score T1 B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] [_Bf_a] [Ae^g]
[V:B]  [_E,_D] [=E,C]
```

A lot of these voicings involve enharmonic respellings of the natural seventh degree.

Comment: Those seem to make much more sense to me than the previous suggestions, but could you show the actual voicings you had in mind, [with ABC snippets](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/documentation-for-abcjs?cb=1)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Alright, but I'm no good with ABC snippets... Could I show you an image of sheet music notation of some voicings? It would look about the same in output...

Comment: @uset45266 I think you should give it a try, ABC is _much_ more efficient for simple stuff like this. But, of course it's up to you. If you like, you can upload a screenshot and I convert it to ABC.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Image uploaded.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks! I'll have to give this ABC a try!

Answer (score 0):

I like staying in the major key.

Imaj9  IVmaj7  vimaj9  V7. simple but resolves nicely. Notice I added a 9 over the minor major 7th

Also using that natural 7 as a passing tone does wonders.

i  imaj7  bVI  iv

or flip it to resolve the bVI to imaj7